# Too many iif statements Access SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a large nested iif statement. I have 16 different fields that I need to assign either a value of 1 or 0, depending on their initial value. Here it is:

```
select
  iif(overlimitexception = "Yes",0,1) as OverLimit,
  iif(CashOutageIdentified = "Yes",0,1) AS CashOutage,
  iif(MissingAuditIdentified = "Yes",0,1) AS MissingAudit,
  iif(NightDropObserved = "Yes",0,1) AS NightDrop, 
  iif(SecurityTestComplete = "No",0,1) AS SecurityTest,
  iif(CashPatternIdentified = "Yes",0,1) AS CashPattern,
  iif(AllClearChange = "No",0,1) AS AllClear,
  iif(RobberyKitReview = "No",0,1),
  iif(EvacPlanReview = "No",0,1),
  iif(KeyComboIssue = "Yes",0,1) AS KeyCombo,
  iif(DualControlIssue = "Yes",0,1) AS DualControl,
  iif(TaIssue = "Yes", 0,1) AS TA,
  iif(CleanDeskIssue = "Yes",0,1) AS CleanDesk,
  iif(MonthlyOpsIssue = "Yes",0,1) AS MonthlyOps,
  iif(OverShortIssue = "Yes",0,1) AS OverShort,
  iif(CashTargetIssue = "Yes",0,1) AS CashTarget 
From [ROM Acknowledgement]
```

I could easily work around this if I was dealing with just one field, but I am dealing with 16. Is there a better way to do this? Thanks for any help!

Comment: nope, I don't think so.

Comment: Btw, those `iif`s are not nested. But do you really want to flag YES as 0?

Comment: You're right, they aren't. I do, we are calculating a total score for risk assessment, lower  = better for our purpose. Thanks!

Comment: I wonder why you store Yes/No information as text fields in the first place?

Comment: Please specify _better_. This is only one operation per column, it can't get much simpler than that.

Answer (score 2):

If you're allergic to `iif`, the following presents a possible alternative:

```
select
    1+(overlimitexception = "Yes") as OverLimit,
    1+(CashOutageIdentified = "Yes") AS CashOutage,
    1+(MissingAuditIdentified = "Yes") AS MissingAudit,
    1+(NightDropObserved = "Yes") AS NightDrop, 
    1+(SecurityTestComplete = "No") AS SecurityTest,
    1+(CashPatternIdentified = "Yes") AS CashPattern,
    1+(AllClearChange = "No") AS AllClear,
    1+(RobberyKitReview = "No"),
    1+(EvacPlanReview = "No"),
    1+(KeyComboIssue = "Yes") AS KeyCombo,
    1+(DualControlIssue = "Yes") AS DualControl,
    1+(TaIssue = "Yes") AS TA,
    1+(CleanDeskIssue = "Yes") AS CleanDesk,
    1+(MonthlyOpsIssue = "Yes") AS MonthlyOps,
    1+(OverShortIssue = "Yes") AS OverShort,
    1+(CashTargetIssue = "Yes") AS CashTarget 
from 
    [ROM Acknowledgement]
```

Answer (score 0):

Assume there is only "No" and "Yes" values in mentioned fields, you can write this

```
  1 - eval(overlimitexception) as OverLimit,
  -eval(SecurityTestComplete) AS SecurityTest,
```

Or a bit faster

```
  3 - len(overlimitexception) as OverLimit,
  -2 + len(SecurityTestComplete) AS SecurityTest,
```